# A question regarding the agreement of possessive pronouns

Tags: grammar-choice, pronouns, agreement

So I have the following to translate:

> Coronas pulchras filia mea parva portat.

And the book answer is:

> My little daughter carries beautiful wreaths.

But what I initially thought:

> The little daughter carries my beautiful wreaths.

So, my question is, is there a way to know where "mea" exactly goes? Context of the sentence? The fact that "mea" is closer to *filia* and *parva* than it is to *coronas*-*pulchras*?

Comment: To add to the good answers: You can say "The little daughter carries my beautiful wreaths." by changing *mea* to *meas*. It might be more natural to start the sentence with *meas*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Latin, an adjective always agrees with the (pro)noun it modifies in **gender, number, and case**. Since Latin is inflected, position is not an important deciding factor, though it can be relevant.

Let's first parse the two nouns in your sentence:

- *coronas*: **feminine, plural, accusative**
- *filia*: **feminine, singular, nominative**

All that's left to do is find out which noun each adjective agrees with. In this case it is very easy, since *pulcher, -chri*, *parvus*, and *meus* are all 1st and 2nd declension adjectives and thus have the same endings as the above nouns.

- *pulchras* ends in -as and agrees with *coronas*.
- *mea* and *parva* end in -a and agree with *filia*

Comment: Ok, I understand my error now. For some reason I assumed that "mea" wasn't a word you could decline. But why do you call it an adjective ? In my book "mea" is refered to as a pronoun. My guess is that "mea" (that which replaces a noun) is acting as an adjective in this specific sentence, right ? Does this make sense grammaticaly speaking ? Thanks

Comment: @copper *meus* is indeed a *possessive pronoun*, but it is an adjective too. Pronouns can be "like" nouns (ego, tu, nos) or "like" adjectives (meus, tuus, noster)

Answer (score 8):

Adjectives always agree with the noun they are modifying in case, gender, and number. Since *mea* is the nominative feminine singular form of *meus, mea, meum* ("my" or "mine"), it goes with *filia* and *parva* which are also in the nominative feminine singular. *Mea* thus could not go with *coronas pulchras*, which is in the accusative feminine plural form.